# Sync any folder to OneDrive without moving it from different drives e.g. D:/ to C:/

Tags: windows-10, sync, onedrive

I'm looking for a way to sync any folder to OneDrive without moving it from different drives e.g. `D:/` to  `C:/` local OneDrive folder. Or ...`mklink /J` does not work due to the different drives.

Any idea?
To describe the situation more detailed. My OneDrive location is on `D:\OneDrive\` and I want to have my Desktop ...`C:\Users\myuser\Desktop` synched to OneDrive cloud.

Answer (score 2):

As `mklink /J` does not work over different drives, use `mklink /D`to
create a directory symbolic link.

See [Microsoft mklink](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/mklink).

Comment: Many thanks for the proposal, but it doesn't work and returns: "Cannot create a file when that file already exists"

Comment: Ensure that you use a name that doesn't already exist.

Comment: I wish this would work, but it doesn't (anymore). See also information from Microsoft about that:  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/can-t-synchronize-onedrive-files-and-folders-from-a-local-file-location-other-than-the-default-onedrive-path-b7eef9d4-4203-431d-8345-fe49254f9da0#:~:text=You%20cannot%20use%20this%20workaround%20in%20reverse.%20The%20original%20or%C2%A0%3CTarget%3E%C2%A0folder%20must%20be%20located%20in%20the%20OneDrive%20directory